# Python comparing list of lists

Tags: python, performance, list, compare

I have a list that contains 10**7 lists in the format:

```
big_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4, 26, 33, 40], [10, 23, 33, 45, 46, 47]]
```

Every list contains 6 unique ints.

I need to compare every list to another list:

```
lst = [1, 3, 4, 10, 23, 46]
```

and return those where list item intersection is less than 3.
So newlist would be:

```
new_list = [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4, 26, 33, 40]]
```

At the moment I'm using set intersection, but it takes about 30 seconds to run

Comment: Can we see your code too, and a clearer, explicit question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> big_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4, 26, 33, 40], [10, 23, 33, 45, 46, 47]]
>>> normal = set([1, 3, 4, 10, 23, 46])
>>> [x for x in big_list if len(set(x).intersection(normal)) < 3]
[[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4, 26, 33, 40]]
```

Comment: At the moment, using intersection is fastest. Converting biglist items to sets beforehand made it even faster, but gave MemoryError with 10**7 items. So this will have to do for now.

Answer (score 4):

```
import numpy as np
biglist = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4, 26, 33, 40], [10, 23, 33, 45, 46, 47]]
oldlist = [1, 3, 4, 10, 23, 46]

b = np.array(biglist)
b[np.array([(b == x).any(axis=1) for x in oldlist]).sum(axis=0) < 3]
```

returns

```
array([[ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 2,  3,  4, 26, 33, 40]])
```

The creation of the numpy array takes some time, but the last line is about twice as fast as the list comprehension with set intersections (for 1e6 lists).

EDIT: The following line is even faster than my code above and needs less memory:

```
b[reduce(np.add, ((b == x).any(axis=1).astype(np.int) for x in oldlist)) < 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a "fast" solution should depend on the specification of your problem. For example, if your reference list is just as short as [1, 3, 4, 10, 23, 46], by sorting every list, we can immediately see that all the lists that start with a num bigger than 10, e.g. [11, x, x, ...] will NOT have more than 3 common elements with the reference. That could already saves a lot of comparisons.